# Geneology - Mechon Yochsin

Tags: family-members

I'm looking to do some family research and have heard about a so called Mechon Yochsin in Boro Park.  Does anyone know their contact information, I can't seem to find it online.

Also, are there any other resources that are beneficial, other than the online websites, that really are not so useful.  Thanks and good shabbos!

Answer (score 3):

[Mechon Yochsin – The Jewish Ancestry Institute](http://5tjt.com/mechon-yochsin-the-jewish-ancestry-institute-2/)

[Mechon Yochsin](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/uncategorized/5242/gavad-visits-mechon-yochsin-institute.html)

> the Sanz-Grobover Rebbe Shlita and his Mechon Yochsin Institute
>   located on 16th Avenue and 48th Street in Boro Park.

[MECHON YOCHSIN](https://www.yellowpagesgoesgreen.org/whitepages/details/ny/MECHON_YOCHSIN/156277)

> Phone: (718) 435-4400
>   1605 48th St,
>   Brooklyn, Kings County, NY-11204

Given what you are looking for, I would suggest joining http://genealogy.stackexchange.com